# Symfony : Add widgets to already defined form

Tags: forms, symfony1, widget

I would like to add widgets (checkboxes) in an already defined form (with configure method).

I can't add them in the definition of the form because the number of widgets varies (according to the object).

I see two ways of doing it :

Either pass a variable into the configure method of the form or maybe use embedded forms.

But which one is the right way ? Is there another solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to pass the object right into the options. In the form you can use the `$this->getOption` method to retrieve the passed options.

Comment: Can we pass any type of data in option ? Do you need to pass the options in the constructor like `$this->form = new myForm(array(), array("variable" => 'test'));` ?

Comment: Correct, it accepts and kind of options. Your constructor is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

I Agree with Don Pinkster on passing option and use it to configure form in configure() method.

But if need it or can't get the value when instanciating the class, you can use from anywhere :

```
$form->getWidgetSchema()->offsetSet($name, $widget);
$form->getValidatorSchema()->offsetSet($name, $validator)
```

The fact you use embedded forms or widget will not change that much, as you can do this after the form is initially configured :

```
$form->embedForm($name, $form2);
```

For just one checkbox I don't see advantages in using embedded form.
In both cases, I suggest you do this in a public method from your form's class, to avoid exploding the form configuration in the action class or elsewhere.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I wasn't aware that it was possible to add a widget in the schema after having instantiate the form !! But  is it ok if the form has been manually created and not generated from Doctrine/Propel model ?

Comment: After a few tries with getWidgetSchema()->offsetSet I could not get it to work. This method seems to be functional only from the configure method :'(

Comment: It should be ok with doctrine generated forms as well. To edit schemas outside the form class I think you need to re-set the widget/validatorSchema on the forme class, as embedForm does it.